# jQuery live, get value, uploadify don't work!

Tags: jquery, ajax, uploadify

I after some ajax stuff I put some number into input field ,and when I try to get that field to paste it in uploadify as script data, it paste empty string, but if I type same value in input field and that try to paste field in uploadify as script data, than works normally.

How to make some live event, or something, to make uploadify pull input that is set on ajax success?

here is the code for script data :

```
scriptData      : {'page_id' : $("#page_id").val()},
```

and on ajax success

```
$("#page_id").val(data.pid);
```

and input type

```
<input type="text" id="page_id" name="page_id" value="" />
```

When I type manual in textbox same value,it works,but when I do not type,uploadify do not send data to php file,problem is with text field that is set on ajax success,don't know how to solve this.

Comment: input field is hidden I just set it as text for now to is value in it

Comment: Please, give us some of the code you're using. It'll make diagnosing your problem much easier for everyone

Comment: here you go,important part is : When I type manual in textbox same value,it works,but when I do not type,uploadify do not send data to php file,problem is with text field that is set on ajax success,don't know how to solve this.

Comment: I think that I need on ajax success to update scriptData,let me check that first

Comment: Have you checked if data.pid is actually returning what you are expecting?

Comment: yes it is good,I need to update uploadify settings on ajax success to,update scriptData,think that is a problem

Comment: So using something like this:
$myUploadifyObj.uploadifySettings('scriptData', {'page_id' : data.pid)
in the success method solved your problem?
Please submit a 'semi' complete example of this as answer to help other users with similar issue.

Comment: I create function update_data and in this function I update uploadifySettings,then I call that function on onSelect,tnx guys,sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateData(){
             $("#uploadify").uploadifySettings('scriptData',{'first' : 'first','page_id' : $("#page_id").val()});
}
```

and I call this function on onSelect.

Tnx guys,sorry

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what's happening, but there is an issue with synchronicity and some of the events.  If you try to update scriptData using the onOpen, onSelect, or onSelectOnce functions, the scriptData won't send with the upload.  You'll need to update the scriptData using a separate js function before you trigger the upload.

Comment: Yes,another issue that I run on is on ie6 and ie7 it just don't fire onComplete function,when image is uploaded.